# Правильная реализация резервирования памяти интерпретатором

Tags: python, интерпретатор

Создаю интерпретатор. Мой алгоритм выделения памяти, когда интерпретатор видит определение/изменение переменной:

1. Из строки выделяются 3 части: 1 - имя переменной, 2 - знак присвоения, 3 - значение переменной.
2. В словарь, создающийся в самом начале работы интерпретатора, вносится пара вида имя_переменной: значение_переменной или изменяется значение, если встречается изменение.

Если встречается использование переменной, то происходит поиск в словаре по ключу.

Вопрос: насколько это быстрый вариант, будет ли он тормозить скорость интерпретатора, при, например, большом количестве переменных? Если да, то какие есть другие способы реализации подобного?

Comment: Для большого (да и для малого) количества переменных надо в качестве контейнера для переменных использовать хеш-таблицу. Скорость интерпретатора всегда зависит от количества переменных, тут уж ничего не поделаешь. Но при хеш-таблице это не так сильно заметно. Вы пишете интерпретатор на Питоне? Он же сам интерпретатор, во всяком случае в девичестве.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 словарь - это и есть хэштаблица. А писать интерпретатор на Python - дело обыденное. В PyPy вон JIT-компилятор на Python написан.

Comment: Просто обычно интерпретаторы пишут на С/С++, чтобы выжать как можно больше скорости. Первый интерпретатор Питона был как раз на С написан.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 я пишу интерпретатор на Python, чтобы набраться опыта и в хотя бы более-менее общих чертах представлять, как должен работать интерпретатор, чтобы потом переделать его на C